# I accidentally deleted virtualenv or rather the "ve" folder on mac os x and now I cannot seem to re-install it via pip

Tags: virtualenv

My pip version is:
pip 8.0.3 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.3-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

When I try and pip install virtualenv, I get this:
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

But where can I find my "ve" folder that I deleted? Or rather how can I get virtualenv in the repo that I am working on? Also, there is no Python folder in my Libraries as the terminal suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I seems you need to create again the virtualenv folder/directory, you can do it with this command

```
virtualenv ve
```

"ve" is the folder/directory name (I'm guessing this is the folder that you delete)

But then you will get an empty virtual enviroment, so you need to install all the libraries that you had in the old virtual enviroment. If you have a requirement.txt file you can do it with the command

```
source ve/bin/activate #This command to activate the virtualenv
pip install -r requirements.txt
```